# Как можно реализовать такую разметку, используя flexbox?

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox

Недавно начал изучать flexbox. Подскажите, как можно реализовать такую разметку?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть на ruSO ответ на подобный вопрос, причем несколько, воспользуйтесь поиском сайта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 0 0 75%;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}

.block{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="block">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="block">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```